# Kafka consumer doesn't received message within time range after change auto.offset.reset=earliest to latest in embeddedKafka junit test

Tags: spring-kafka, offset, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka

In a recent common library upgrade, I found Kafka consumer doesn't received message within the expected time(2 minutes). After compared with the code and did lots of tests, looks it is caused by `auto.offset.reset=latest`(it was `earliest`). What would be the root cause?

Env:

```
Spring-Boot 2.7.11; spring-kafka-test 2.8.11
```

main Consumer config:

```
max.poll.records=250
max.poll.interval.ms=300000
heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
enable.auto.commit=false
auto.offset.reset=latest
auto create topic = true
```

can't copy the code, but it mainly uses:

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerConntainerFactory
@KafkaListener annotation
```

the main change is `auto.offset.reset=earliest` to `latest`

follow-up:
refer to
[Embedded Kafka Test - The Kafka listener is not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352547/embedded-kafka-test-the-kafka-listener-is-not-invoked)

[EmbeddedKafka sending messages to consumer after delay in subsequent test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312373/embeddedkafka-sending-messages-to-consumer-after-delay-in-subsequent-test)

[gary russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) mentioned that it might send the message before the container completely starts.
so what will happen in this case?

- does the message arrived at the topic?
- with "offset=latest", it won't point to the message I sent?

update again(May/19):

as suggested, I added these code(but keep auto.offset.reset=latest):

```
ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, 1) // configured 1 partition in embeddedkafka
```

However, I saw in log:

```
Publishing records xxx here
o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState: ....Resetting offset for partition xxxx to position FetchPosition(offset=2,...)
```

I supposed offset reset should happen before publishing and offset=0?